# Calculating the number vectors from an intersection

Tags: qgis

So I would like to calculate how many lines go from an intersection. So in more detail I have mapped out trails and then worked out the where these line intersect (node). I now want to work backwards and see how many lines come from the intersection and to which other intersections they connect with. Is this possible to do in QGIS version 3?

Answer (score 1):

If you computed the nodes you should be able to build a query between this point layer (nodes) and your line layer (trails) ? Something like :

```
select node_id, count(*) from nodes, trails
where st_intersects(nodes.geometry, trails.geometry)
group by node_id
```

Comment: did that help ?

Comment: thanks for follow up ...